# Convert Minute to Integer from datetime data type MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date-arithmetic

in this query i need to get how much minute has passed away from current time,
this is my query :

```
select Status,CallDate,
CONVERT(int,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CallDate,GETDATE())) as downtime
from servicerequest
where status = 'Open' and downtime < 180;
```

the query show data like this

```
Status  Calldate                downtime  
Open    2020-06-30 02:03:17.927  548           
Open    2020-06-30 02:18:07.800  533           
Open    2020-06-30 08:11:42.600  180           
Open    2020-06-30 08:11:00.000  180           
Open    2020-06-30 08:22:16.740  169           
Open    2020-06-30 08:02:52.610  189           
Open    2020-06-30 08:39:30.760  152           
Open    2020-06-30 08:39:00.000  152
```

as you can see the query is not working properly, because it should not show data below 180 (int), any ideas how to do it?
thank you

Comment: I didn't understand your query well, you aliased converted valued with `downtime`. and tried to use it in the `where` clause. you can't use an alias name in the same query.

Comment: Do you have any field named `downtime` in the table `servicerequest`?

Comment: hi thank for your comment, no i dont have `downtime` in my table.,
downtime = datetime type data that i get only minute and convert it to integer,
so in my opinion this data can now be used for searching what rows has more than 180 minute of downtime,

Comment: This is the point I want to aware you, the `downtime` in the `select` clause is not the same `downtime` in the `where` clause. you should write something like this in the `where` clause:

`where status = 'Open' and CONVERT(int,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CallDate,GETDATE()))< 180;`

Comment: wow its working, thank vakili !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!